# Why is creating an array with inline initialization so slow?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, initialization

Why is inline array initialization so much slower than doing so iteratively? I ran this program to compare them and the single initialization takes many times longer than doing so with a `for` loop.

Here's the program I wrote in `LinqPad` to test this.

```
var iterations = 100000000;
var length = 4;

{
    var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
    timer.Stop();
    "Array- Single Init".Dump();
    timer.Elapsed.Dump();
}

{
    var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        var arr = new int[length];
        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
            arr[j] = j;
        }
    }
    timer.Stop();
    "Array- Iterative".Dump();
    timer.Elapsed.Dump();
}
```

Results:

```
Array - Single Init
00:00:26.9590931

Array - Iterative
00:00:02.0345341
```

I also ran this on **VS2013 Community Edition** and the **latest VS2015 preview** on a different PC and got similar results to my `LinqPad` results.

I ran the code in `Release` mode (i.e.: compiler optimizations on), and got very different results from above. The two code blocks came out very similar this time. This seems to indicate it is a compiler optimization issue.

```
Array - Single Init
00:00:00.5511516

Array - Iterative
00:00:00.5882975
```

Comment: The add one is weird, because IIRC, the "list initializer syntax" actually *is* calling `Add` in a loop

Comment: Your iterative lists are adding 10 items, the others are adding four.

Comment: Your test may not be valid, because the compiler can optimize out dead code, and you're not doing anything with the objects created in the loops.

Comment: i have corrected the code to have the same number of iterations, and updated the results

Comment: And now you can see that the times for lists are about as different as would be expected (what you now have is the difference between an unrolled loop and a regular loop), making that half entirely irrelevant.

Comment: I see that, I will remove the parts regarding the list.

Comment: I ran this on my machine and it took 0.1 seconds for the first version and 1.9 seconds for the second, which sounds about right.

Comment: Removed my answer with timings that were contrary to what you have posted, because I ran on Release. On Debug I can recreate your results. So is it a matter of something being terribly underoptimized?

Comment: [Non-optimized VS2012 .NET4.5 results](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dhCDtu1U) vs 
[Optimized VS2012 .NET4.5 results](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cfeh6kpv)

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer Obviously if you disable optimizations, the code will be terribly optimized.  Why would that be a surprise to anyone?  If you want to care about the timings of operations, you need to have optimizations on, else the results are meaningless.

Comment: And that's why I removed my answer, it was an oversight

Comment: On OSX/Mono, the first initialization took 1.65 seconds.  The second tool 1.321 seconds.  After reading @Sriram's answer, I changed direct init to use variables (x1 - x4) and initialized like `new int[] {x1, x2, x3, x4}`.  For that run the initialization of the first loop took 1.315 seconds and the second 1.319 seconds, so they were comparable.  I'll have to wait until I get home to run the test on .NET on my windows box.

Comment: To me this looks like the compiler in debug mode simply does not do optimizations. A lot of this syntactical sugar makes the compiler's job a lot more difficult to create good, optimized output. In reality the two should technically produce the almost identical byte code, which seems to be the case in release mode. In debug mode it seems to just do things "close enough" so you have things working. It could be that method 1 creates a lot more complex debugging information.

Comment: Did you ever swap the order of the two variants? It could allocate memory for the first run, being much faster in the second.

Comment: Did anyone realize that the inline version creates an array of {1,2,3,4} and the iterative one creates the array of {0,1,2,3}?

Comment: @displayName Haha yeah, but that doesn't affect performance :)

Comment: @Some1Pr0: I didn't say it does.. :D Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: a fair point @displayName, I don't want to change them to match because  the question is 10 months old now and adding a `+` operation would change the IL a bit i imagine :). The point is just creating some array and its contents are obviously meaningless.

Comment: This should even the playing field.  var arr = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

Comment: What surprises me is that any code is generated at all. The optimizer should be able to spot that arr is never used, so creating it is pointless to start with. I would expect zero execution time in Release builds (certainly for the first loop).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First of all, **profiling at the C# level will give us nothing** since it will show us the C# code line which takes longest to execute which is of course the inline array initialization, but for the sport:

[image: Profiling Results]

Now when we see the expected results, lets **Observe the code at the IL Level** and try to see what is different between the initializations of the 2 arrays:

- First of all we will look at the **standard array initialization**:

  [image: For Loop]

  Everything looks good, the loop is doing exactly what we expect with no noticeable overhead.
- Now let's take a look at the **inline array initialization**:

  [image: Inline Array Initializer]

  - The first 2 lines are creating an array at the size of 4.
  - The third line duplicates the generated array's pointer onto the evaluation stack.
  - The last line set's the array-local to the array that was just created.

Now we will focus on the 2 remaining lines:

The first line (`L_001B`) loads some *Compilation-Time-Type* whose type name is `__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=16` and it's field name is `1456763F890A84558F99AFA687C36B9037697848` and it is inside a class named `<PrivateImplementationDetails>` in the `Root Namespace`. if we look at this field we see that it contains the desired array entirely just as we want it coded to bytes:

```
.field assembly static initonly valuetype <PrivateImplementationDetails>/__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=16 1456763F890A84558F99AFA687C36B9037697848 = ((01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00))
```

The second line, calls a method which returns the initialized array using the empty array that we have just created in `L_0060` and using this *Compile-Time-Type*.

If we try to look at this method's code we will see that it is [implemented within the CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable]
public static extern void InitializeArray(Array array, RuntimeFieldHandle fldHandle);
```

So either we need to find it's source code in the published CLR sources, which I couldn't find for this method, or we can **debug in the assembly level**.
Since I am having trouble with my *Visual-Studio* right now and having problems with it's assembly view, Let's try another attitude and **look at the memory writes** for each array initialization.

Starting from the loop initialization, at the beginning we can see there is en empty `int[]` initialized (in the picture `0x724a3c88` seen in [*Little-Endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is the type of `int[]` and `0x00000004` is the size of the array, than we can see 16 bytes of zeros).

[image: Empty Array Memory]

When the array is initialized we can see that the memory is filled with the same *type* and *size* indicators, only it also has the numbers 0 to 3 in it:

[image: Initialized Array Memory]

When the loop iterates we can see that the next array (signed in red) it allocated right after our first array (not signed), which implies also that each array consumes `16 + type + size + padding = 19 bytes`:

[image: New Array]

Doing the same process on the *inline-type-initializer* we can see that after the array is initialized, **the heap contains other types also** other than our array; this is probably from within the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InitializeArray` method since the array pointer and the *compile-time-type* token are loaded on the evaluation stack and not on the heap (lines `L_001B` and `L_0020` in the IL code):

[image: Inline Array Initialization]

Now allocating the next array with the *inline array initializer* shows us that **the next array is allocated only 64 bytes after the beginning of the first array!**

[image: 2 Inline Initialized Arrays]

**So the** ***inline-array-initializer*** **is slower at the minimum because of few reasons**:

- Much more memory is allocated (unwanted memory from within the *CLR*).
- There is a method call overhead in addition to the array constructor.
- Also if the *CLR* allocated more memory other than the array - it probably does some more unnecessary actions.

Now for the difference between *Debug* and *Release* in the *inline array initializer*:

If you inspect the assembly code of the debug version it looks like that:

```
00952E46 B9 42 5D FF 71       mov         ecx,71FF5D42h  //The pointer to the array.
00952E4B BA 04 00 00 00       mov         edx,4  //The desired size of the array.
00952E50 E8 D7 03 F7 FF       call        008C322C  //Array constructor.
00952E55 89 45 90             mov         dword ptr [ebp-70h],eax  //The result array (here the memory is an empty array but arr cannot be viewed in the debug yet).
00952E58 B9 E4 0E D7 00       mov         ecx,0D70EE4h  //The token of the compilation-time-type.
00952E5D E8 43 EF FE 72       call        73941DA5  //First I thought that's the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InitializeArray method but thats the part where the junk memory is added so i guess it's a part of the token loading process for the compilation-time-type.
00952E62 89 45 8C             mov         dword ptr [ebp-74h],eax
00952E65 8D 45 8C             lea         eax,[ebp-74h]  
00952E68 FF 30                push        dword ptr [eax]  
00952E6A 8B 4D 90             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-70h]  
00952E6D E8 81 ED FE 72       call        73941BF3  //System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InitializeArray method.
00952E72 8B 45 90             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-70h]  //Here the result array is complete  
00952E75 89 45 B4             mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax
```

On the other hand the code for the release version looks like that:

```
003A2DEF B9 42 5D FF 71       mov         ecx,71FF5D42h  //The pointer to the array.
003A2DF4 BA 04 00 00 00       mov         edx,4  //The desired size of the array.
003A2DF9 E8 2E 04 F6 FF       call        0030322C  //Array constructor.
003A2DFE 83 C0 08             add         eax,8  
003A2E01 8B F8                mov         edi,eax  
003A2E03 BE 5C 29 8C 00       mov         esi,8C295Ch  
003A2E08 F3 0F 7E 06          movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi]  
003A2E0C 66 0F D6 07          movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0  
003A2E10 F3 0F 7E 46 08       movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi+8]  
003A2E15 66 0F D6 47 08       movq        mmword ptr [edi+8],xmm0
```

The debug optimization makes it impossible to view the memory of arr, since **the local at the IL level is never set**.
As you can see this version is using `movq` which is for that matter **the fastest way to copy the memory** of the compilation-time-type to the initialized array by copying 2 times a `QWORD` (2 `int`s together!) which is exacly the content of our array which is `16 bit`.

Comment: Very impressive answer, you're a master of MSIL ! Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's little-endian, not big-endian. Big-endian means the most significant byte comes first. These are little endian: `0x00000004` is stored as `04 00 00 00`, `0x724a3c88` is stored as `88 3c 4a 72`, with the least significant bytes (the little ends) first.

Comment: I stop by this answer every so often to try and grasp a little bit more of it every time

Comment: The source for InitializeArray is here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/c98155df54da9247e598068cc956dfe9aede610e/src/classlibnative/bcltype/arraynative.cpp#L1373

Answer (score 6):

Static array initializes are implemented bit differently. It will store the bits in the assembly as a embedded class which will be named something like `<PrivateImplementationDetails>...`.

What it does is stores the array data as bits inside the assembly in some special location; which will then be loaded from the assembly and it will call `RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray` to initialize the array.

*Do note that if you use reflector to view the compiled source as `C#` you'll not notice anything what I'm describing here. You'll need to look at the `IL` view in reflector or any such decompiling tools.*

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable]
public static extern void InitializeArray(Array array, RuntimeFieldHandle fldHandle);
```

You can see this is implemented in `CLR` (marked as `InternalCall`), which then maps to `COMArrayInfo::InitializeArray` (***ecall.cpp*** in ***sscli***).

```
FCIntrinsic("InitializeArray", COMArrayInfo::InitializeArray, CORINFO_INTRINSIC_InitializeArray)
```

`COMArrayInfo::InitializeArray` (lives in ***comarrayinfo.cpp***) is the magical method which initializes the array with the value from bits embedded in assembly.

I'm not sure why this takes a lot of time to complete; I don't have good explanations for that. I guess it is because it goes and pulls the data from the physical assembly? I'm not sure. You can dig into the methods by yourself.
But you can get some idea that it doesn't gets compiled to as what you see in your code.

You can use tools like `IlDasm`, and `Dumpbin` to find more about this and of course download ***[sscli](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917)***.

FWIW: I've got this information from `Pluralsight` course by "bart de smet"

Comment: You are talking about code that doesn't actually get used.  The jitter optimizer removes it and there's no array left at all.  Basic problems with the question are that the benchmark does not represent realistic code and is not executed with the optimizer enabled.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I noticed when optimize switch turned on it runs damn fast (obviously gets optimized). When optimization is off, maybe this magic is what causing the performance penalty?