# initializing variable before returning it is faster in c#

Tags: c#, .net

On the LeetCode question two sum, I noticed that when I initialized the returned array in one line with the return statement, like this:

```
return new int[2] { i, o };
```

The code was significantly slower than when written like this:

```
int[] returnArr = new int[2] { i, o };
return returnArr;
```

The one line return used less memory for obvious reasons, but it was extremely slow. Why?

Response time: 275ms

```
public class Solution 
{
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) 
        {
            for (int o = i + 1; o < nums.Length; o++) 
            {
                if (nums[i] + nums[o] == target) 
                {
                    return new int[2] {i, o};
                }
            }
        }

        return new int[0];
    }
}
```

Response time: 181ms

```
public class Solution 
{
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) 
        {
            for (int o = i + 1; o < nums.Length; o++) 
            {
                if (nums[i] + nums[o] == target) 
                {
                    int[] returnArr = new int[2] { i, o };
                    return returnArr;
                }
            }
        }

        return new int[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times did you test this?

Comment: 2 for each. I averaged out the times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is creating an array with inline initialization so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180708/why-is-creating-an-array-with-inline-initialization-so-slow)

Comment: Please show how you have reached those values. The code used to bench these functions should be also analyzed.

Comment: @Steve it was submitted on to LeetCode. https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/submissions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Release mode, IL body of the both TwoSum methods are the same;

```
IL_0014: ldc.i4.2
IL_0015: newarr [System.Runtime]System.Int32
IL_001a: dup
IL_001b: ldc.i4.0
IL_001c: ldloc.0
IL_001d: stelem.i4
IL_001e: dup
IL_001f: ldc.i4.1
IL_0020: ldloc.1
IL_0021: stelem.i4
IL_0022: ret
```

In Debug mode, there are only 2 more opcodes. For first example, IL body of the method;

```
IL_001c: ldc.i4.2
IL_001d: newarr [System.Runtime]System.Int32
IL_0022: dup
IL_0023: ldc.i4.0
IL_0024: ldloc.0
IL_0025: stelem.i4
IL_0026: dup
IL_0027: ldc.i4.1
IL_0028: ldloc.1
IL_0029: stelem.i4
IL_002a: stloc.3
IL_002b: br.s IL_0058
```

Second example;

```
IL_001c: ldc.i4.2
IL_001d: newarr [System.Runtime]System.Int32
IL_0022: dup
IL_0023: ldc.i4.0
IL_0024: ldloc.0
IL_0025: stelem.i4
IL_0026: dup
IL_0027: ldc.i4.1
IL_0028: ldloc.1
IL_0029: stelem.i4
IL_002a: stloc.3

IL_002b: ldloc.3   // Pushes local variable, returnArr to the 3rd index of the evaluation stack.
IL_002c: stloc.s 4 // Pops latest pushed value from evaluation stack

IL_002e: br.s IL_005c
```

In Release mode, there are no difference because of compiler optimizations, so there shouldn't be any differences.
In Debug mode, second code pushes variable to the stack, and then pops it again, so it should run slower anyways.

For more accurate results, you should use benchmark libraries like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) and should run the benchmark methods for millions or billions times and get the average/mean time.